# Google Bigquery: Remove rows where column value is distinct (count = 1) without referencing table

Tags: sql, group-by, filtering, distinct, google-bigquery

Given a table, I wish to remove rows where a column value is distinct.

So if we want to do this for column2 on matrix A

```
     c1 c2 c3
A = |1  2  4 |
    |1  2  5 |
    |1  1  6 |
```

yields

```
     c1 c2 c3
A = |1  2  4 |
    |1  2  5 |
```

This can be done easily by

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE c2 IN
(SELECT c2 FROM Table GROUP BY c2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Unfortunately, in the middle of a subquery, you don't have the data stored in a Table and I don't want to create a view as I need to do this filtering all in one query.

Any ideas on how I can still filter out distinct rows with respect to a single column without referencing a Table in the subquery?

The solution should be of the form:

```
SELECT <something goes here>
FROM <the subquery which outputs A goes here>
<anything you want here that is legal Bigquery - e.g. can't reference A>
```

and there is no table to reference.

Comment: Why you won't want to reference it in the subquery?

Comment: Because I'm not filtering a table, I'm filtering the results of a query.

Comment: Be explicit with the example as the proposed solution shall work.

Comment: I clarified the question - proposed solution does indeed work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bigquery supports window functions, so you might be able to do this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col2) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

This still references the table in a subquery, but that is the only reference to the table.

Comment: This worked. Sorry for my initial confusion - well done and thank you!

Comment: @cgn . . . Ironically, the bigquery documentation is vague on whether window functionality applies to aggregation functions.  I figure if the database is powerful enough to support `row_number()` and `lag()`, then it must.  Plus, I figure it is designed in response to hive, and hive does support this functionality.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for nice solution, I will make sure that documentation on window functions is updated. P.S. BigQuery is _not_ designed in response to Hive :)

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky . . . Having never said that before, it will be easy for me not to repeat it.  I do find a lot of similarities between the two approaches, from a SQL perspective, it is seems as though one likely inspired the other.  Cheers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the insight - I agree with your mention of the similarities of hive, but am less experienced in their application  - thanks for a very clear answer :)